# SSRS Choose Parameter to Show in Header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a report for my customers where they can input a Premise Number, Tax ID, Service Number, or Address to search by. I've set these four options as my parameters.

I'd like to show whichever they have selected in my header. Right now, my header looks like this;

```
Service for
Premise: __whatever they select__
Tax ID:
Service ID:
Address:
```

Expression Code looks like this;

```
="BACKFLOW SERVICE / DEVICES / TESTS" & vbcrlf &
"for Premise#: " & Parameters!premise.Value & vbcrlf &
"for Tax Parcel ID: " & Parameters!TaxParcelID.Value & vbcrlf &
"for Premise-Svc: " & Parameters!SvcNum.Value & vbcrlf &
"for Address: " & Parameters!SvcAddr.Value
```

But, instead, I would like for my header to only show whatever they've selected. If they're searching by address, I'd like for my header to say;

```
Service for
Address: ___address here___
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking the parameters for values with an IIF Statement. You can do something like what is below.

```
="Service for " & vbcrlf & 
IIF(ISnothing(Parameters!premise.Value), '', "for Premise#: " & Parameters!premise.Value & vbcrlf) & 
IIF(ISnothing(Parameters!TaxParcelID.Value), '', "for Tax Parcel ID: " & Parameters!TaxParcelID.Value & vbcrlf) & 
IIF(ISnothing(Parameters!SvcNum.Value), '', "for Premise-Svc: " & Parameters!SvcNum.Value & vbcrlf) &
IIF(ISnothing(Parameters!SvcAddr.Value), '',"for Address: " & Parameters!SvcAddr.Value)
```